# the map $x\mapsto x^{n}$ for finite groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $m$ and $n$ be relatively prime to $m$ show the map $x\mapsto x^{n}$ is injective.

Comment: Do you know the Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: Hint: being coprime means that there exist integers $t,s$ such that $tn+sm=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\gcd(n,m)=1$ there exists $d$ such that $dn\equiv 1\pmod m$. The map $x\mapsto x^{d}$ is the inverse of $x\mapsto x^{n}$ thus it is injective.

Answer (score 5):

Since $n$ is relatively prime to $m$ then there's $p,q$ such that
$$pm+nq=1$$
and let $x,y$ s.t. $x^n=y^n$ then $ex^{nq}=ey^{nq}$ so $x=x^{pm+nq}=y^{pm+nq}=y$ and the given map is injective.